# Adding new ball to arraylist causes all the subsequent ball positions to be shifted

Tags: java, processing

I need to implement bouncing balls that can be added at the position the mouse is pressed and bounce off the walls. However right now I can get the first ball to work but all the subsequent balls appear off the mouse position and has weird wall collision detection.

I suspect its due to my for loop since when i iterate through the list backwards the balls appear at the correct position but all the ball positions reset when I add a new ball.

```java
ArrayList<Ball> balls;

void setup() {
    size (640 , 480, P3D);
    noSmooth();
    // Create an empty ArrayList (will store Ball objects)
    balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
}

void draw() {
    background(1);

    // Frame
    stroke(255);
    line(0, 0, -500, width, 0, -500);
    line(0, 0, -500, 0, height, -500);
    line(0, height, -500, width, height, -500);
    line(width, height, -500, width, 0, -500);
    line(0, 0, -500, 0, 0, 0);
    line(width, 0, -500, width, 0, 0);
    line(0, height, -500, 0, height, 0);
    line(width, height, -500, width, height, 0);

    //for (int i = balls.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    for (int i= 0; i<balls.size(); i ++){
        Ball ball = balls.get(i);
        ball.move();
        ball.display();
    }  
}

void mousePressed() {
    // A new ball object is added to the ArrayList (by default to the end)
    balls.add(new Ball(mouseX, mouseY, random(-5.0,5),random(-5.0,5)));
}

// Simple bouncing ball class
class Ball {
    PVector pos;  
    PVector vel; 
    float grav = 0.1;

    Ball(float posX, float posY, float velX, float velY){
        pos = new PVector(posX, posY, 1);
        vel = new PVector(velX, velY, 1);
    }

    void move() {
        // Add gravity to speed
        //vel.y += grav;
        // Add speed to y location
        pos.add(vel);

        if (pos.x>width-50) {
            vel.x*=-1;
        }
        if (pos.y>height-50) {
            vel.y*=-1;
        }
        if (pos.z>500) {
            vel.z*=-1;
        }
        if (pos.x<50) {
            vel.x*=-1;
        }
        if (pos.y<50) {
            vel.y*=-1;
        }  
        if (pos.z<0) {
            vel.z*=-1;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        translate(pos.x,pos.y, -pos.z);
        sphere(50);
        noFill();
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm meant to do to fix it so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the call to [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html). This function doesn't only define a translation matrix, it defines a matrix and concatenates (multiplies) the matrix to the current matrix. This causes that the first ball is correct, but every following ball is off the expected position.
Use [`pushMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) push (store) the current matrix, before the individual translation matrix for a ball is set. Use [`popMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) to pop (restore) the current matrix, after the ball is drawn. e.g.:

```java
class Ball {

    // [...]

    void display() {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(pos.x, pos.y, -pos.z);
        sphere(size);
        noFill();
        popMatrix();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for